# selecting a menu item

Tags: java, swing, menu

1)I have GUI Menu below; From this menu, I should select "Add Job" menu item.

2)By selecting this menu item, I want to show the information belongs to a hashmap collection in a JTextFiled by pressing AddJob Button.

"peeskillet" already answered 2nd part. Thnks to him.

How can I do 1st part? How can I combine two parts?

Thanks,
Serb

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: And what did you try?

Comment: I was dealing with  "ClearListButtonHandler" which clear the information. But, since my submission is tomorrow, I could not try anything regarding my question yet.

Comment: Are both the windows supposed to be open at the same time?

Comment: JMenuItem addJobItem = new JMenuItem("Add Job");
JMenuItem listWaitingItem = new JMenuItem("List Waiting");

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't get the flow of how the program is supposed to work. Can you be a little more clear?

Comment: I had justcreated these ones before

Comment: private void makeMenus(JFrame frame)

Comment: Add an `ActionListener` to the menu item??

Comment: Are you just asking _HOW_ to open a new window?

Comment: is the name of the method which create the main frame's menu bar.

Comment: @serb It's better if you update your question with some code until downvoting starts.

Comment: @serb, if your question about how to use Menus try following tutorial, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

Comment: • selecting the "Add Job" menu item, makes visible:
• a text field which allows the user to enter the customer name
• a set of checkboxes for selecting the features of the job: "On site", "Shorthand", "Translation"
• the button labelled "Add Job"

Comment: On clicking the "Add Job" button, use information in the text field

Comment: This is what is wanted

Answer (score 0):

i think in swing you cant combine two components but you can make one hidde

Comment: • selecting the "Add Job" menu item, "makes visible":
• a text field which allows the user to enter the customer name
• a set of checkboxes for selecting the features of the job: "On site", "Shorthand", "Translation"
• the button labelled "Add Job"

Comment: you are right. as you said I should make the "Add Job" menu item visible by selecting it from the menulist.

Comment: what ide are you with? i had intellij and i can do that kind of stuff with the gui swing builder in it,its really easy with intellij

Answer (score 0):

> "• selecting the "Add Job" menu item, makes visible: • a text field which allows the user to enter the customer name • a set of checkboxes for selecting the features of the job: "On site", "Shorthand", "Translation" • the button labelled "Add Job"

If you just want to show the `Add Frame`

```
addMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something to make the frame visible like
        addJobFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

If you are wondering how to add a `Job` to the map

```
addJobButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        boolean selection1 = cbox1.isSelected();
        boolean selection2 = cbox2.isSelected();
        boolean selection3 = cbox3.isSelected();

        String custName = textField.getText();

        jobsMap.put(custName, new Job(custName, selection1, selection2, selection3));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanksalot. I will try this ASAP. Appreciate